# calling web service soap, ERROR The https URL hostname does not match the Common Name (CN) on the server certificate in the client's truststore

Tags: java, ssl, soap, ioexception, saaj

Hey i trying to call a soap web services with SAAJ

i using Wildfly 10

i trying to add this system properties to standalone.xml but not working

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="java.protocol.handler.pkgs" value="com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol"/>
    <property name="org.jboss.security.ignoreHttpsHost" value="true"/>
    <property name="cxf.tls-client.disableCNCheck" value="true"/>
</system-properties>
```

i getting the following error

20:53:08,208 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21) Caused by: java.io.IOException: IOException invoking https://myip:port/b2cgw/PAGOS_B2C: The https URL hostname does not match the Common Name (CN) on the server certificate in the client's truststore.  Make sure server certificate is correct, or to disable this check (NOT recommended for production) set the CXF client TLS configuration property "disableCNCheck" to true.

private static ResponseEntity callSoapWebService(String soapEndpointUrl, String soapAction, String apikey, long timestamp) {
        try {
            // Create SOAP Connection
            SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

```
        // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(soapAction, apikey, timestamp), soapEndpointUrl);

        // Print the SOAP Response
        System.out.println("Response SOAP Message:");
        soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println();

        soapConnection.close();

        return new ResponseEntity(org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.OK);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.err.println("\nError occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server!\nMake sure you have the correct endpoint URL and SOAPAction!\n");

        e.printStackTrace();

        return new ResponseEntity(org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

please help, i dont have any cxf config file